# Android JetPlayer Midi Playback missing notes

Tags: java, android, midi

I've been banging my head against Midi on the Android SDK all day and, although I have music running through the JetCreator all right, there's still an issue where certain notes on certain instruments just aren't playing.  It almost sounds like the octave range is capped or something.

My general hypothesis is that the default DLS file android uses doesn't support a full range of octaves...or something like that.  I tried importing gm.dls from the Windows install into the jetfile but I had the same problem so maybe that's not it.  Programmatic music is very new to me.  There's very little user-developed documentation or help in this regard...apparently DLS is really old and everyone uses soundfonts now....which begs the question why does JetCreator still use DLS?

Anyways I'm looking for a little guidance from someone who's familiar with the library.

Comment: it turns out the files i was playing were too long?  I cut them down into single loop tracks and suddenly they played just...not sure if maybe it was just a coincidence...

Answer (score 0):

Given your comment, I'm guessing that you probably tried to queue too many notes to the instruments at the same time. Did you manage to get the issue fixed?